# "Открыты для открытий" — есть ли здесь речевая ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, тавтология

Задали найти речевые ошибки в СМИ. Увидела рекламу с лозунгом "Открыты для открытий". По сути это тавтология (повтор однокоренных слов), но в то же время мне кажется, что это довольно часто встречающееся словосочетание в рекламах и, возможно, это уже не будет как ошибка. Как думаете, можно ли взять это словосочетание как речевую ошибку или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Это не речевая ошибка, **а стилистический прием**. Здесь нет избыточности (плеоназма), но есть **тавтология** – повторение однокоренных слов.

Это выражение часто используется для названия статей, например: ***Открыт для открытий.*** В Ульяновске начал работу центр молодежного инновационного творчества «Воплощение». http://ulpravda.ru/narodka/rubrics/sobytiia/otkryt-dlya-otkrytii

Тавтология используется в пословицах и поговорках, в устойчивых выражениях: *сказка сказывается, сидеть сиднем, горе горькое, ходить ходуном, без вины виноватый.*

В то же время **повтор в заголовке должен быть именно художественным приемом**, то есть привлекать к себе внимание необычностью, яркостью впечатления, новизной. Но если название применяется часто, то новизна теряется, сочетание превращается в штамп, и тавтология перестает себя оправдывать.

Answer (score 1):

> Задали найти речевые ошибки в СМИ. Увидела рекламу с лозунгом "Открыты для открытий". По сути это тавтология (повтор однокоренных слов), но в то же время мне кажется, что это довольно часто встречающееся словосочетание в рекламах и, возможно, это уже не будет как ошибка. Как думаете, можно ли взять это словосочетание как речевую ошибку или нет?

Раз уж не удалось найти речевые ошибки в рекламе, давайте поищем их в Вашем вопросе. Я надеюсь, после этого тема "Речевые ошибки" станет Вам немного ближе и понятней.

- "В рекламах". Неверное употребление мн. ч. Корректно: "в рекламе" или "в рекламных объявлениях".
- "Часто встречающееся словосочетание в рекламах". Неверный порядок слов.  Корректно: "Часто встречающееся в рекламе словосочетание" или "Словосочетание, часто встречающееся в рекламе". А еще лучше: "Мне кажется, что это словосочетание часто встречается в рекламе".
- "Не будет как ошибка". Корректно: "Это словосочетание довольно часто встречается в рекламе, и, возможно, **оно уже не считается ошибкой**".
- "Взять это словосочетание как речевую ошибку". Корректно: "Как думаете, можно ли **рассматривать** это словосочетание как речевую ошибку?" или "Как думаете, можно ли привести  это словосочетание в моей работе как пример речевой ошибки?"
- "Можно ли... или нет?" Корректно: "Можно ли...?" (без *или нет*) или "Можно... или нет" (без *ли*).

Comment: Вообще-то я не диссертацию тут пишу. А задаю вопрос, да, я знаю, что не очень корректно написано, но как-то это грубо с Вашей стороны. Вместо того, чтобы просто ответить на конкретно поставленный вопрос или же просто промолчать, Вы начинаете докапываться до слов в моем вопросе, который был задан в спешке и не для Вашей контрольной проверки на граммотность.

Comment: @L_I Я не хотел Вас обидеть, и если все-таки обидел, то прошу прощения. Я думал, Вам (да и другим читателям) мой разбор ошибок будет полезен.